# Reordering the list based on values from another list?

Tags: python, list

How to reorder the first list based from another list in Python?

I cannot reorder the 2 list so here's my code:

```
import random
numElements1 = int(input("Enter the number of elements for first list: "))
numElements2 = int(input("Enter the number of elements for second list: "))

randomlist = random.sample(range(10, 99), numElements1)
print(randomlist)

randomlist2 = random.sample(range(10, 99), numElements2)
print(randomlist2)
```

Comment: `[50, 40, 70, 60, 90]` here it contains only one `60` but output has two 60's `[60, 60, 90, 40, 70]`

Comment: Doesn't appear you've tried anything yet to change any ordering of any lists

Comment: Sorry, I changed it now...

Comment: can you explain the relation b/w two lists i can't see any relation

Comment: The two list are random list, then arr[] list will be reorder based on the index[] list

Comment: How are you taking the index list?

Comment: The index list is also a random list

Comment: if you want to order it based on index output should be this `[40, 60, 90, 50, 70]` not this `[60, 50, 90, 40, 70]`

Comment: Yes you're right

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reorder-a-array-according-to-given-indexes/

Comment: Please show your own attempt at the solution. You've generated some lists. Now use the index values to build a new one

Comment: it's a one liner, once you understand https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip It's an important function in python, but nobody here is just going to give you ... oh crap nevermind. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sorted()` with `zip()`

```
arr, index = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(arr, index), key=lambda x: x[1])))

print(arr) #[40, 60, 90, 50, 70]
print(index) #[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a={}
for i in index:
    a[i]=randomlist[i]

for i,j in sorted(a.items()):
    out_index.append(i)
    out_arr.append(j)
```